# Adjective to describe the quality of liking to teach and/or having a talent for teaching?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, american-english

I'm looking for a concise way to express the quality of enjoying or preferring to impart knowledge to other individuals. In a way, the counterpart to a person who is *teachable* or *takes instruction well*. I considered *instructive*, but it is not often used to describe people, and doesn't feel warm enough for my intentions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

A **natural** or 
**born** or
**natural-born** teacher.

> **natural-born**
>   adjective  : able to do something well immediately or from the very first time -- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/natural-born

Answer (score 1):

You might consider, ***pedagogy-minded***

> 1. the function or work of a teacher; teaching.
> 2. the art or science of teaching; education; instructional methods.
>
> [Random-House Kennerman Webstee's Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pedagogy)
>
> *In order for pedagogy-minded applied linguists to be able to anticipate cases where learners are likely to misconstrue the meaning of a phrasal expression, they need to put themselves in their learners' shoes.*
>
> [Bilingual Figurative Language Processing](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22morbid+humor%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif5vmf4dnLAhUEXhoKHfXDCK0Q_AUIBygA&biw=619&bih=407&dpr=2#q=%22pedagogy+minded%22)

Answer (score 0):

To have an **aptitude** for teaching.

Aptitude

Full Definition of aptitude

1
a :  inclination, tendency

b :  a natural ability :  talent

2
:  capacity for learning

3
:  general suitability :  aptness

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aptitude)